# How is fingerId correctly used in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

**EDIT:** *As I've found out finger ID gets the same number as the touch's original index value, I made a method resetting the saved finger ID from a discarded touch to -1. A complete answer is posted.*

---

I'm trying to implement 2 finger multitouch control for my simple shooting game, where one finger shot continuously affect the rotation of the player if first held down at the defined area lower at the screen, and the other controls the shooting button which can also be loaded to shoot more powerful bullets.

At first I tried storing the touch position when TouchPhase = Began in a Vector3 array with two places, with the other classes checking if and which one of the values in the array comply with the rule for starting their activity. The issue was that the finger index seems to drop down if an earlier finger is lifted, so if I pressed for example aiming -> shot button and then lifted aiming the aiming button became stuck in loading as it was trying to track touch(1) which actually became (0).

The solution it seemed should be using fingerId, which produces a consistent number for a touch regardless of its index. The thing is - what I'm writing works even worse than before. It activates functions even when I'm pressing at the wrong places, so it seems the if statement complies even when it shouldn't. What's wrong with the code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int aimID;
    public static int shootID;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        aimID = 0;
        shootID = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Vector2 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                if (pos.x == Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -2.5f * SceneScale.ratio, 2.5f * SceneScale.ratio) &&
                    pos.y <= Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).y + (2 * SceneScale.ratio))
                {
                    aimID = Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId;
                }
                else if (Vector2.Distance(pos, ShotButton.position) <= ShotButton.scale.x)
                {
                    shootID = Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class ShotButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool[] time;
    static public Vector3 scale;
    static public Vector2 position;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        position = new Vector2(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y);
        time = new bool[2];
        time[0] = false;
        time[1] = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < 2; i++)
        {
            time[i] = false;
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId == TouchControls.shootID)
            {
                time[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public static bool isDead = false;

    public float rot;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId == TouchControls.aimID)
            {
                rot = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position).x * 80 / (2.5f * SceneScale.ratio);
            }
        }
        rot = Mathf.Clamp(rot, -80, 80);
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rot);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this has received no answers and I haven't found a different method, I'll post what I've found to work — even though there might be other more effective solutions.

Finger ID matches the original index of the touch, which could be 0 or above. So I saved a unique integer type for for each controlling method and initialized it with the value -1. When touch with TouchPhase.Began falls within the boundaries defined for one of the buttons or controlling areas, I give the unique integer type the recorded finger ID value, which is then used by the respective method to find the index at which the touch is during each frame, and when the touch with this finger ID returns TouchPhase.Ended it gives the saved integer the value of -1 once again, which can't be found in any touch and thus it halts the controlling method.